# Npm install specific version does not work in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, eslint

I'm trying to install a specific version of npm package within the `node:alpine` image (latest tag), so this is what I specified in my Dockerfile:

Edit (this is the full Dockerfile):

```
FROM node:alpine as build-stage
ARG SONAR_VERSION=4.6.0.2311
RUN apk add --no-cache zip unzip
RUN wget -c https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-$SONAR_VERSION-linux.zip

RUN unzip -q sonar-scanner-cli-$SONAR_VERSION-linux.zip
RUN rm sonar-scanner-cli-$SONAR_VERSION-linux.zip

# Adding the $install_directory/bin directory to path
RUN cd sonar-scanner-$SONAR_VERSION-linux
RUN echo $PWD
RUN export PATH="$PATH:/$PWD/bin"

RUN npm i -g eslint@6.7.2
RUN npm i -g eslint-plugin-vue --save-dev
```

However when I run & execute the built image, the installed version of eslint is the latest instead of what I'd specified in the Dockerfile.

Result from `npm list -g`:

```
/ # npm list -g
/usr/local/lib
+-- eslint-plugin-vue@7.9.0
+-- eslint@7.25.0
`-- npm@7.11.2
```

If I run `npm i -g eslint@6.7.2` within the container itself, the version from `npm list -g` will be exactly the one I specified.

What is the reason of this scenario?

Comment: Why aren't these packages (and the corresponding version constraints) in your `package.json` file?

Comment: can you post your whole dockerfile and the package.json

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to run a static code analysis in my CI pipeline, but I don't need each and every dependencies of the project itself... so I came up with an idea to create a custom docker image with these 2 libraries preinstalled (which are required as part of the static code analysis flow, and they don't have to be re-installed every time the CI pipeline is ran)

Comment: @TruckDriver I have added the full Dockerfile; as for the package.json file, I only need these 2 out of all libraries in this image (versions are same).

Comment: I think I found the reason why the `eslint` ended up not being the version I stated: if I put the `npm i eslint` statement at the last, it will install the exact version I wanted... So it seem like the other package (`eslint-plugin-vue`) installed the latest version of `eslint` when it was the last statement in my Dockerfile

Comment: Basically it means the order of adding the package has a chance to cause the previously installed package to be overridden